# Code Smells in Java

Tags: java, refactoring

I am trying to learn about different code smell and to refactor the code accordingly. I have learnt about the Long Methods , Type Checking but I have problem in identifying these code smells. How can I if it is long method or type checking? If it has lot of ifs or switch what can it be considered as? What are various techniques to identify different code smells?

Answer (score 2):

Smelly code is code that is hard to read or hard to understand. There is no universal rules and tolerance depend on a programmer per programmer basis. Read about code smells, and code smells catalogues, and see if you think you have ever encountered such issues. Such things come with practice and experience.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049457/java-tool-to-improve-my-clean-code-development) as well.

Are you sure that's the right way to go? Why try to memorize all possible patterns when there are plugins that can do the job for you?

We use the [SonarLint plugin](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/index.html) in our office that reads our code as we write, and highlights nearly all of our smells, apart from duplicated code across files. As you keep using the plugin, you'll end up memorizing the code smells anyway.